# Library ItemUpdating - distinction between versioning of existing files, and changing metadata of existing files

Tags: event-receivers, splistitem, versioning

I am currently facing challenges in distinction between updating an item, and creating a new version of same item. 
The ItemUpdating eventreceiver is hit in both cases.

Requirements for the library are following...

- Restricted, so that no metadata chan be changed in the library after creation of an SPListItem
- Allow a file to be versioned, but without any changes in metadata that are presented to the user.

I am aware of the sequence of events with this setup. They are also mentioned in Damon Armstrong writeup on eventreceivers (Armstrong, 2012).
Armstrong addresses the distinction between a check-in and other events...

```
if (properties.AfterProperties["vti_sourcecontrolcheckedoutby"] == null &&
    properties.BeforeProperties["vti_sourcecontrolcheckedoutby"] != null)
```

Are there any simular indicators that chan be checked, when distincting the origin of the ItemUpdating event receiver?

---

**Reference:**

Armstrong D., 2012 *Managing ItemUpdating and ItemUpdated Events Firing Twice in a SharePoint Item Event Receiver* [Online] available from: http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-tools/managing-itemupdating-and-itemupdated-events-firing-twice-in-a-sharepoint-item-event-receiver/ (Accessed: 20.NOV.2012)

Answer (score 0):

check if properties.AfterProperties["vti_contenttag"] works for you

Comment: Hi Diptarag. `vti_contenttag` Shows the value null sometimes - but I cannot see when this is happening